# Include local dll in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my C# project I'm referencing one of my company's DLLs, which is not on NuGet (as it's not public) and my pipeline in Azure DevOps keeps failing because it says it cannot find the reference.

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'YYY' does not exist in the namespace 'ZZZ' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Following the advice from [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/272365/how-to-add-a-reference-dll-to-continous-integratio.html) I have copied the dll in my solution and I'm referencing it from there, so the dll is version controlled and lives in the repo.
Here an extract from the csproj:

```
<Reference Include="ZZZ.YYY, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\PrivateReferences\ZZZ.YYY.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

The solution builds perfectly from my machine, but it keeps failing on Azure. What am I missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT AFTER Bright Ran-MSFT REPLY**
Here is the extract from my yaml:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool: 'Default'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '<GUID of my Feed>'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can publish these DLLs as yourself custom NuGet package to an [**Azure Artifacts**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops) feed on Azure DevOps. Then in the pipeline for your project, you can use the [NuGet restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to restore the package into your project.

After publishing the package, when building your project via Visual Studio on your local machine, you also can connect to the Azure Artifacts feed to restore the package into your project.

**[UPDATE]**

Have you checked the output console logs of the pipeline run to see what caused the package can't be restored? Whether the reason is **unauthorized error**, such as **`401`** or **`403`**?

If so, before the  **NuGet restore task**, you need to use the [**NuGet Authenticate task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to provide the authentication information. Here you also need to create a [**NuGet service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-nuget) for use.

Normally, the feed you set up to publish yourself custom packages is private, when accessing the feed in the pipeline, the authentication is required.

On your local Visual Studio, due to you have log in with your account, VS will automatically authenticate with your account when you connect to the feed.

Comment: I have created the nuget package with my dlls and I created an artifact feed adding that nuget package. Now if I use that nuget (from Azure) in my local solution it works, but Azure is still not getting it in the pipeline. I've added my yaml (containing the restore task) to the answer for clarity.

Comment: Hi @AndreaTassera, I have updated my answer with more information. Please check it. If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Looking more closely to the log, it seems that the NuGet task is working and can get the package correctly ("Added package blah blah). The issue seems to be in the VSBuild task. At some point it says it cannot resolve the reference (Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ZZZ.YYY". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.), it tries to consider a few paths and then gives that Error CS0234 because it cannot find the package, hence cannot build

Comment: Actually I didn't realise I forgot to swap to the azure artifact in one of the projects. Seems to be working now! Thanks for the solution!